# How to interact with my first defi smart contract in remix?

Tags: solidity, remix, fallback-function

I found this tuto online : https://cryptomarketpool.com/create-a-defi-bank-that-pays-interest-yield-farm/ and i deployed my token and my smart contract on testnet via remix.

The issue is that i am a total noob and i really don't know to interact with this contract. Not sure what is the difference between `hasStaked` and `isStaking`.

When trying to execute the contract with some address and some amount, as below. The transaction goes well, but nothing happen. My LINK does not disappear from my wallet.

Next step is to code a small API with python, but first i need to understand how to use this smart contract.

[image]

Below is my smart contract :

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.12;


interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint);
    function transfer(address recipient, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);
    function approve(address spender, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint amount
    ) external returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
}


contract mycontract {
    
    // call it DefiBank
    string public name = "DefiBank";
    
    // create 2 state variables
    address public LINK;
    address public bankToken;


    address[] public stakers;
    mapping(address => uint) public stakingBalance;
    mapping(address => bool) public hasStaked;
    mapping(address => bool) public isStaking;


    // in constructor pass in the address for LINK token and your custom bank token
    // that will be used to pay interest
    constructor() public {
        LINK = 0x01BE23585060835E02B77ef475b0Cc51aA1e0709;
        bankToken = 0x5A39644Axxxxxxxxxxxxxxx849cBf102be;

    }


    // allow user to stake LINK tokens in contract
    
    function stakeTokens(uint _amount) public {

        // Trasnfer LINK tokens to contract for staking
        IERC20(LINK).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);

        // Update the staking balance in map
        stakingBalance[msg.sender] = stakingBalance[msg.sender] + _amount;

        // Add user to stakers array if they haven't staked already
        if(!hasStaked[msg.sender]) {
            stakers.push(msg.sender);
        }

        // Update staking status to track
        isStaking[msg.sender] = true;
        hasStaked[msg.sender] = true;
    }

        // allow user to unstake total balance and withdraw LINK from the contract
    
     function unstakeTokens() public {

        // get the users staking balance in LINK
        uint balance = stakingBalance[msg.sender];
    
        // reqire the amount staked needs to be greater then 0
        require(balance > 0, "staking balance can not be 0");
    
        // transfer LINK tokens out of this contract to the msg.sender
        IERC20(usdc).transfer(msg.sender, balance);
    
        // reset staking balance map to 0
        stakingBalance[msg.sender] = 0;
    
        // update the staking status
        isStaking[msg.sender] = false;

} 


    // Issue bank tokens as a reward for staking
    
    function issueInterestToken() public {
        for (uint i=0; i<stakers.length; i++) {
            address recipient = stakers[i];
            uint balance = stakingBalance[recipient];
            
    // if there is a balance transfer the SAME amount of bank tokens to the account that is staking as a reward
            
            if(balance >0 ) {
                IERC20(bankToken).transfer(recipient, balance);
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }

    event Received(address, uint);
    receive() external payable {
        emit Received(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see an error into your contract in this line

```
// transfer LINK tokens out of this contract to the msg.sender
 IERC20(usdc).transfer(msg.sender, balance);
```

If you'll stake the LINK token, you mustn't use the usdc variable but you must to change it with LINK variable like this:

```
// transfer LINK tokens out of this contract to the msg.sender
IERC20(LINK).transfer(msg.sender, balance);
```

For the problem of stake, the user must to approve the contract to spend yours token. To do this, you must go into LINK smart contract (on testnet) and call the approve function connecting your wallet and inserting the address of smart contract and the amount.

The difference between hasStaked and isStaking is:

- hasStaked: is a mapping concern all users that they have already staked the tokens. And if they staked in a previous time, the user is not added into stakers mapping;
- isStaking: is a mapping concern all users that they having (at the moment) your tokens staked into a smart contract.